# Can't link to an anchor on another page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, anchor, link-to

From the research I've done this code should work. But for some reason I keep getting the error that the page is not found. Maybe it's because it's going though my Main_controller?

```
public function privacy($page='privacy')  {                     
            $this->load->view($page);            
         }
```

The VIEW:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('main/privacy#myModal-privacy') ?>">Privacy Policy<span class=""></span></a>
```

The idea is have the privacy popup from anywhere I would want to link to it. Right now I have to put the text on the same page and then link to it through the id="myModal-privacy".

Thanks for any and all input.

Answer (score 0):

The codeigniter url convention is: "mysite.com/controller/function/id. see [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#uri-segments)

your link contains a hashtag, which is not working as id like you intend, change it to the CI-convention like this:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('main/privacy/myModal-privacy') ?>">Privacy Policy<span class=""></span></a>
```

which will now send in the url `myModal-privacy` as id and you'd load this page in the controller:

```
$this->load->view('myModal-privacy');
```

Comment: It's not working. By the way, I don't think the ID that's talked about in your docs link is referring to the # css id. 

Right now, if I link with the hash to the controller it works but I still have to have privacy text on the same page as view which is what I'm trying to avoid. But thanks. If you think of something else please let me know.

Comment: right now you are always loading `$this->load->view('privacy')`, because with your current `a href` you are not sending a valid id to the controller you just load the controller, the hashtag is irrelevant

Comment: Understood. I tried it the way you suggested and it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I'm overlooking something. I'll continue trying. If I find the answer will let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a way to set an anchor $data variable and pass it to the view along with the page load? Not sure of the code, but maybe something like this:

$data-anchor = 'myModal-privacy';
$this->load->view('$page, $data-anchor');

Answer (score 0):

In your question controller name is `Main_Controller` and in the view, you are using `main`.

If you are not defining route then use same controller name to call the function

```
<a href="<?= site_url('Main/privacy#myModal-privacy') ?>">Privacy Policy<span class=""></span></a>
```

Comment: Sorry. The controller is "Main". I put the underscore here to show that it is the controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add a question mark?

Correct Code

```
<a href="<?= site_url('main/privacy/?#myModal-privacy') ?>">Privacy Policy<span class=""></span></a>
```

Comment: Hi. but that doesn't seem to work either. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Play around a little bit try `<a href="<?= site_url('main/privacy/#myModal-privacy') ?>">Privacy Policy<span class=""></span></a>`

Comment: or try `<a href="<?= site_url('main/privacy?#myModal-privacy') ?>">Privacy Policy<span class=""></span></a>`